# How to implement Forgot your password feature Using Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, forgot-password, reset-password

I have to implement a forgot your password module in my app, I have implemented firebase cloud messaging for chat and notification functions. Every time I login to my app I login into firebase as well for chat and messaging purposes.

Now for forgot your password I have to send password reset email through my app to change the password in my database and again in firebase to change the password in firebase database. Is there any way to implement this in a single email or any other way?

Open to all suggessions.

Comment: Suggestion: Don't store passwords in the database itself

Comment: in my database or in firebase database??

Comment: Unfortunatly it isn't very clear what exactly you are talking about here (database, firebase realtime database, firebase authentication). Therefore I can't do more than give a general suggestion

Comment: It is for firebase authentication. When i login in my application i need to authenticate twice once for firebase and once for my own database. So if i change password in firebase database i need to change password in my database as well.

Comment: Can  you clarify what *my database* is. Why make a user authenticate twice? Why do you have a separate database - how about just using Firebase as your database?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Comment: yes i have checked your answer. It is not what i needed!

Comment: @SaugatJonchhen can you please specify what exactly happened after using my code?what part didnt work and code do where you searching for!I am ready to help

Comment: That was not the solution i was looking for it is ok when the user is authenticated but for me i needed it without authentication of user. Anyway i have already solved this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use firebase default method as:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(emailAddress)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // do something when mail was sent successfully.
                } else {
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

This will send a password reset email to the user.

Comment: I have this code, this will send reset password for firebase and will only change password in firebase database then how can i change password in my database?? I have to check for both firebase and my database while login.

Answer (score 0):

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updatePassword(newPassword.getText().toString().trim())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Password is updated!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to update password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```

After sending the email link this is the code you need!